# Interfacing with a button module using 3x MCP23018 port expanders

Tags: gpio, python, i2c

I have recently picked up a keypad I wish to use in a Raspberry Pi project. It has an i2c interface, with 20 buttons, each with an LED backlight. The buttons/LED's are connected to 3x MCP23018 port expanders as inputs/outputs. I have worked out this mapping fine, but am having a couple of issues when writing python code to work with this.

At the moment, I have written a simple python app that enables/disables the backlight on a button when you press it. It is using polling as the adafruit MCP library does not support interrupts. It is on github here https://github.com/mehstg/dimepi

`keypad.py` is the main application, and `pin_mappings.py` is the mapping of input/output pins to the letter assigned to the button.

My issue is, the registering of button presses seems very unreliable. Some times I have to press a button 2-3 times before it registers a press. Other times it works fine. Not sure if the issue is when the processor is off doing something else it misses the presses, or whether there is a flaw in my code, but any help appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import busio
import digitalio
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017
import pin_mappings
import time

class Keypad:

    buttons = {}
    leds = {}

    def __init__(self):
        i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
        left = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x25) #Leftmost port expander
        middle = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x22) #Middle port expander
        right = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x20) #Rightmost port expander

        #Set up input pins
        for k, v in pin_mappings.keymap_left.items():
            pin = left.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            self.buttons[v] = pin
        for k, v in pin_mappings.keymap_middle.items():
            pin = middle.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            self.buttons[v] = pin
        for k, v in pin_mappings.keymap_right.items():
            pin = right.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            self.buttons[v] = pin

        # Set up LED's
        for k, v in pin_mappings.ledmap_left.items():
            pin = left.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            pin.value = True
            self.leds[v] = pin
        for k, v in pin_mappings.ledmap_middle.items():
            pin = middle.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            pin.value = True
            self.leds[v] = pin
        for k, v in pin_mappings.ledmap_right.items():
            pin = right.get_pin(k)
            pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
            pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
            pin.value = True
            self.leds[v] = pin

    def setKeysOff(self):
        for k,v in self.leds.items():
            if k != "credit":
                v.value = True
                time.sleep(0.01)#Gives a nice transition
        return True

    def setKeysOn(self):
        for k,v in self.leds.items():
            if k != "credit":
                v.value = False
                time.sleep(0.01)#Gives a nice transition
        return True

    def setKeyOn(self,key):
        self.leds["key"].value = False

    def setKeyOff(self,key):
        self.leds["key"].value = True

    def toggleKey(self,key):
        if self.leds[key].value == True:
            self.leds[key].value = False
        elif self.leds[key].value == False:
            self.leds[key].value = True

    def setCreditOff(self):
        self.leds["credit"].value = True
        return True

    def setCreditOn(self):
        self.leds["credit"].value = False
        return True

    def getKeypress(self):
        for k,v in self.buttons.items():  
            if v.value == False:
                    return k
        return False

keypad = Keypad()

while True:
    o = keypad.getKeypress()
    if o != False:
        keypad.toggleKey(o)
        print(o + " pressed")
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Essentially it sets up the input/output pins based on the mapping file (shown below), then sits in a while true loop and waits for input.

Mapping file:

````
    0 : "2",
    3 : "1",
    4 : "A",
    6 : "B",
    8 : "C",
    11 : "D",
    12 : "4",
    15 : "3"
}

keymap_middle = {
    8 : "E",
    11 : "F",
    12 : "6",
    15 : "5"
}

keymap_right = {
    0 : "8",
    3 : "7",
    4 : "G",
    7 : "H",
    9 : "J",
    11 : "K",
    12 : "10",
    14 : "9"
}

ledmap_left = {
    1 : "2",
    2 : "1",
    5 : "A",
    7 : "B",
    9 : "C",
    10 : "D",
    13 : "4",
    14 : "3"
}

ledmap_middle = {
    6 : "credit",
    9 : "E",
    10 : "F",
    13 : "6",
    14 : "5"
}

ledmap_right = {
    1 : "8",
    2 : "7",
    5 : "G",
    6 : "H",
    8 : "J",
    10 : "K",
    13 : "10",
    15 : "9"
}```
````

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question.  That needs to include the github code as well as a main program.  Few people will be willing to guess what you are doing.

Comment: added info as requested